# iAd banner misplaced in a tab bar based application

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode, swift

When I try to add an iAd banner in my tab bar based application,
every time the banner is hide by the tab bar. (I'm using Xcode 6.4 with iOS 8.4)

So I found this link [Apple iAd Samples](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/iAdSuite/Introduction/Intro.html), where apple made some samples apps with iAd integration,
but when I run there "TabbedBanner" sample app, the same issue occur !

Can someone explain me what happening with this iAd banner ?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

because of the layout constraints sometimes the Xib and Storyboard files get the placing of certain items wrong.

First make sure that the iAd in the Xib file is at the bottom and not below.

If it is, then just move the iAd on the Xib 44 pts up. that should place it in the right position!